# Change the owner of a file in a running Docker container with an attached volume in Windows

Tags: docker

I am running Docker in Windows (not the native version as I don't have Windows Pro).

I am running a image with an attached volume like so using the Docker Quickstart terminal (MinGW64) (I also used Windows Command Prompt):

```
docker run --rm -it -v /c/Users/yahya/example:/host-shared debian bash
```

When I run `ls -l` on the `/host-shared` directory I get this:

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 0 Aug  6 20:38 hi
```

However when I try to change the owner of this file like so:

```
chown www-data:www-data hi
```

and the run `ls -l` again; the owner has not changed!

I believe this may be a Windows only problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it (on Linux though) and it actually works. It may not work as you expect or need it, but it does work.

The files in the container belongs to the user `www-data:www-data`, as for the host, it belongs to the user `1:33`.

If the host and container users do not match then it is because the UID and GID differs between the container and the host. The solution is to create a user using `useradd --uid $HOST_USER_UID --gid $HOST_USER_GID $USER_NAME`, then you're set!

---

#### Update

Here is the issued commands:

```
root@5665d3b794a2:/# ls -lh host-shared/aklm/
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug  6 07:03 aze
-rw-rw-r--. 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug  6 07:03 azer
root@5665d3b794a2:/# chown -R root:root /host-shared/
root@5665d3b794a2:/# ls -lh host-shared/aklm/
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  6 07:03 aze
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  6 07:03 azer
```

Docker Server Version: 1.11.2

Comment: I'm only concerned with the user in the container (not the host). Are you sure it worked. Did the owner change when you ran `ls -l`. What version of docker are you using?

Comment: But was that folder a mounted volume?

Comment: The container was run with: `docker run --rm -it -v /home/user/tmp:/host-shared debian bash`, so yes it was. Also, if it were not mounted, I could not have check the owner on the host (cf the `1:33`)

Comment: I now believe this is a Windows only problem. Hence why you had no problem. I updated the question!

Comment: Not being a Windows user, I leave you from here and wish you luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please update answer to reflect the fact you're answer is only suitable for Linux