# Docker - Change the owner of a file for a container in Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following simple Docker file:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

VOLUME /var/www/html

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I run it using docker-compose with the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    image: image_name
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
```

I then connected to the container like so:

```
docker exec -it container_name_foo_1 bash
```

When I run `ls -l` on the `/var/www/html` directory I get something like this:

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 staff 0 Aug  6 20:38 hi
```

However when I try to change the owner of this file like so:

```
chown www-data:www-data hi
```

and the run `ls -l` again; the owner has not changed!

I believe this may be a Windows only problem.

I mentioned a similar issue here: [Change the owner of a file in a running Docker container with an attached volume in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799160/change-the-owner-of-a-file-in-a-running-docker-container-with-an-attached-volume/38801549), which is still unanswered. (This question is slightly different as this question deals with DockerFile rather than an already running Docker container).

From reading other Stack Overflow answers, I was told to change the permissions before mounting the volume in the Docker file (which I did), but did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
docker exec -u root -it container_name_foo_1 chown other:user -R /path
```

Answer (score 2):

To use posix permissions on an NTFS mounted filesystem you need to provide a user mapping file. Basically you need a way to convert `www-data` to a valid NT SID. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851) answer on askubuntu, and this [ntfs-3g article](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/) for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: I have read some of the commands on the first link and am really confused. What commands do I have to actually run when using Docker, as many of the commands mentioned seems to relate to a VM?

Comment: Examples of problems I'm having is that the command `blkid` dosen't return anything. This may be becuase `/var/www/html` is not treated as a mounted filesystem.

Comment: the second link is broken, here's the fixed one https://web.archive.org/web/20200321035617/https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/